# Trying to change 4 images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

## Situation

Hello guys. I've created four images side by side, the idea is: when i click in one of them, this image will be changed for another one ( with better resolution) and the others( case exists) will be returned to poor resolution.

## Code

#### HTML

```
<img data-id="0" src="assets/images/front/grupo/grupo-bignardi-2.gif" alt="Grupo Bignardi - Soluções em Papel" class="pure-img imagensSelecionaveis"/>          
<img data-id="1" src="assets/images/front/grupo/bignardi-papeis.gif" alt="Bignardi Papéis" class="pure-img imagensSelecionaveis"/>
<img data-id="2" src="assets/images/front/grupo/jandaia.gif" alt="Jandaia" class="pure-img imagensSelecionaveis"/>
<img data-id="3" src="assets/images/front/grupo/jandaia-atacado.gif" alt="Jandaia - Atacado em Papelaria" class="pure-img imagensSelecionaveis"/>
```

#### Javascript

```
$('.imagensSelecionaveis').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    if(id == 3) {
        $(this).attr('src', 'assets/images/front/grupo/jandaia-atacado-2.png');
    }
});
```

I don't know how to proceed. In this case for example, the fourth image will be changed for one better and i don't know how specify to another images return to your poor states.

Answer (score 0):

HTML tags can have data attributes that specify certain data for that tag. In this case, I suggest adding two data attributes to each image, one each for low-res and high-res.

`<img src="assets/images/front/grupo/grupo-bignardi-2.png" data-high-res="grupo-bignardi-2.png" data-low-res="grupo-bignardi-2-low-res.png"/>`

And from there you can swap out the src attribute with whichever image you need.

Comment: alright, but just one imagem will can be watch in full resolution while the others don't. The idea is change a low quality image in .gif for a better in .jpg. So, i'm using a single field for src.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. So add to your image tag the data attributes I explained. Then when the image is clicked, set the src attribute to the data-high-res attribute. And when you mouseout of that image, set the src attribute back to the data-low-res attribute. This will swap your image between high and low res images

Answer (score 0):

Add data attributes for hi-res and low-res.  Automatically switch them all back on click and then change the one you clicked.

```
<img data-id="0" 
 data-hi-res="assets/images/front/grupo/grupo-bignardi-2-hi.png" 
 data-low-res="assets/images/front/grupo/grupo-bignardi-2-low.png"
 src="assets/images/front/grupo/grupo-bignardi-2.png" 
 alt="Grupo Bignardi - Soluções em Papel" class="pure-img imagensSelecionaveis"/>
```

jQuery

```
$('.imagensSelecionaveis').on('click', function(){

  // Reset all images to low-res
  $('.imagensSelecionaveis').each(function( index ) {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('low-res'));
  });

  // The clicked image shows hi resolution image    
  $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('hi-res'));
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/24rtLwgn/

Comment: You won't need the `data-id` if this approach solves your problem.